# Puppeteer : Chromium hangs when clicking

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to click on an element until that given element disappear from the DOM but it seems to make the browser hang.

Here is a code snippet , the goal is to actually paginate through the website by clicking the "Next" button until it disappear.(end of pagination)

```
  const jobs = await page.evaluate(
    (container, next) => {
      let next_page = document.querySelector(next);
      while (next_page !== null) {
        next_page.click();
      }
      return true;
    },
    container,
    next
  );
```

Also the loop doesn't seem to be infinite since the element actually disappears from the DOM in a certain point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `next_page` element after each iteration, otherwise you would never get the `null` value in order to exit the while loop.

```
const jobs = await page.evaluate(
  (container, next) => {
    let next_page;
    do {
      next_page = document.querySelector(next);
      next_page.click();
    } while (next_page !== null);
    return true;
  },
  container,
  next
);
```

Comment: Hey, Lanken, welcome to S.O.! For the answer to be even more iseful, why not add some code showing how to fix the issue in question?

Comment: Thanks, Vaviloff, will do next time at once.